# Identification of influential observations in regression with library car

Tags: r, regression

Can somebody explain why `library(car)` finds influential observations here?:

```
library(car) 

x = seq(1, 5, len = 100)

set.seed(99)

y = 2*x + 1 + rnorm(length(x), 0, 0.00005)

plot(x,y)      # no influential observations!!

infl = influencePlot(lm(y ~ x)) 
infl # 4 influential observations??
```

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [help page for the function](https://rdrr.io/cran/car/src/R/influencePlot.R):

> The default ‘method="noteworthy"’ is used only in this function and
> indicates setting labels for points with large Studentized residuals,
> hat-values or Cook's distances.

And the default settings:

> id=TRUE’ is equivalent to ‘id=list(method="noteworthy", n=2, cex=1,
> col=carPalette()[1](https://rdrr.io/cran/car/src/R/influencePlot.R), location="lr")’

Using your example it looks like this:

[image]

It basically labels the 2 most extreme values for Studentized Residuals (y-axis) and 2 most extreme values for Hat-values (x-axis).

If you want the 3 most extreme, you can do:

```
influencePlot(lm(y ~ x),id=list(method="noteworthy",n=3))
```